# CoreData: Is it possible to emulate SQLite transaction behavior when we have batch update operation in between?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I know that there is no feature similar to SQLite transaction, when using CoreData.

I try best to emulate SQLite transaction behavior using the following code template.

```
context.perform {
    do {

        /*
            Place all operations right here, to emulate SQLite transaction
            behaviour.
        */

        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
            }
        }
    } catch {
        context.rollback()
    }
}
```

**This enables me to run several DB operations within transaction liked behavior. If one of the DB operations fails, NONE of any DB operation will take effect.**

Currently, I have the following operations within the "transaction" block.

1. `context.delete` on table `NSTabInfo`.
2. using context to create an item in table `NSTabInfoTrash`.
3. Perform batch update on table `NSPlainNote`.

---

For testing purpose, I try to throw an exception just before `context.save()`.

I notice operation 1 and operation 2 can be rolled back, but not the operation 3 (batch update)

I was wondering, is there a way to still emulate SQLite transaction behavior when we have batch update operation in between?

The below are the actual code snippet for reference.

---

```
func permanentDelete(_ objectID: NSManagedObjectID) {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    let backgroundContext = coreDataStack.backgroundContext
    let currentTimeMillis = Date.currentTimeMillis
    
    backgroundContext.perform {
        do {
            guard let nsTabInfo = try backgroundContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as? NSTabInfo else { return }
            
            // We will never delete tab info without name.
            guard let originalName = nsTabInfo.name else { return }
            
            let uuid = nsTabInfo.uuid
            
            backgroundContext.delete(nsTabInfo)
            
            _ = NSTabInfoTrash(context: backgroundContext, uuid: uuid, syncedTimestamp: currentTimeMillis)
            
            // This batch update operation unable to be rolled back!
            try renameLabels(
                backgroundContext,
                from: originalName,
                to: nil,
                syncedTimestamp: currentTimeMillis
            )
            
            RepositoryUtils.saveContextIfPossible(backgroundContext)
        } catch {
            backgroundContext.rollback()
            
            error_log(error)
        }
    }
}

func renameLabels(_ backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext, from: String, to: String?, syncedTimestamp: Int64) throws {
    let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "NSPlainNote")
    batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", from)
    batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = [
        "label": to,
        "syncedTimestamp": syncedTimestamp
    ]
    batchUpdateRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
    
    let batchUpdateResult = try backgroundContext.execute(batchUpdateRequest) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
    
    guard let batchUpdateResult = batchUpdateResult else { return }
    guard let managedObjectIDs = batchUpdateResult.result else { return }
    
    if let managedObjectIDs = managedObjectIDs as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
        if !managedObjectIDs.isEmpty {
            let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey : managedObjectIDs]
            CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.mergeChanges(changes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Batch functions are of course very different beasts than your vanilla CRUD operations so you shouldn't mix them for transaction handling since they are executed using their own transaction. If you want one single atomic transaction then you need to replace the batch update with a normal update.